# Mutually recursive lists

Tags: code-golf, sequence, decision-problem

Let's define a simple function \$f\$ which takes an integer and produces a list:

\$
f(n) = [g(1),g(2),\dots,g(n)] \\
g(n) = [f(0),f(1),\dots,f(n-1)]
\$

We can then calculate the first couple of values for \$f(n)\$:

```
0 ->
 []
1 ->
 [[[]]]
2 ->
 [[[]],[[],[[[]]]]]
3 ->
 [[[]],[[],[[[]]]],[[],[[[]]],[[[]],[[],[[[]]]]]]]
4 ->
 [[[]],[[],[[[]]]],[[],[[[]]],[[[]],[[],[[[]]]]]],[[],[[[]]],[[[]],[[],[[[]]]]],[[[]],[[],[[[]]]],[[],[[[]]],[[[]],[[],[[[]]]]]]]]
```

And we notice that each one is bigger than the last and has the last list as a prefix to itself.

So we could say that \$f(\infty)\$ is the infinite sequence such that each \$f(n)\$ is the first \$n\$ entries of it.

Now infinite lists of lists of lists ... are a little complicated so instead we will just treat \$f(\infty)\$ as an infinite sequence of opening and closing brackets.  The `,`s are redundant so we just omit them.  In fact we don't need to even deal with the brackets since there are only two values we can make a binary sequence!

```
1110011011100001101110001110011011100000011011100011100110111000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000001...
[[[]][[][[[]]]][[][[[]]][[[]][[][[[]]]]]][[][[[]]][[[]][[][[[]]]]][[[]][[][[[]]]][[][[[]]][[[]][[][[[]]]]]]][...
```

### Task

Your task is to output the binary sequence given by \$f(\infty)\$.  You can choose any two distinct values for `1` and `0`.  IO otherwise uses [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) defaults.  Read [the tag wiki](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/sequence/info) for precise info.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so answers will be scored in bytes with the goal being to minimize your source code size.

### Test cases

Here's the first 10000 entries

```
1110011011100001101110001110011011100000011011100011100110111000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000000011011100011100110111000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000011011100011100110111000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000111001101110000110111000111001101110000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000111001101110000110111000111001101110000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000011011100011100110111000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000011011100011100110111000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000000011011100011100110111000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000011011100011100110111000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000111001101110000110111000111001101110000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000000000011011100011100110111000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000011011100011100110111000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000111001101110000110111000111001101110000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000111001101110000110111000111001101110000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000000111001101110000110111000111001101110000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000011011100011100110111000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000011011100011100110111000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000000000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000011011100011100110111000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000000011011100011100110111000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000011011100011100110111000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000111001101110000110111000111001101110000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000111001101110000110111000111001101110000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000011011100011100110111000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000011011100011100110111000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000000011011100011100110111000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000011011100011100110111000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000111001101110000110111000111001101110000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000000000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000000111001101110000110111000111001101110000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000011011100011100110111000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000011011100011100110111000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000000000111001101110000110111000111001101110000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000011011100011100110111000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000011011100011100110111000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000111001101110000110111000111001101110000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000011011100011100110111000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000000000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000111001101110000110111000111001101110000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000000111001101110000110111000111001101110000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000011011100011100110111000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000011011100011100110111000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000000000011011100011100110111000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000011011100011100110111000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000111001101110000110111000111001101110000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000111001101110000110111000111001101110000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000000111001101110000110111000111001101110000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000011011100011100110111000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000011011100011100110111000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000000000000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000111001101110000110111000111001101110000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000000111001101110000110111000111001101110000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000011011100011100110111000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000011011100011100110111000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000000000011011100011100110111000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000011011100011100110111000001110011011100001101110001110011011100000000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000111001101110000110111000111001101110000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000111001101110000110111000111001101110000001101110001110011011100000111001101110000110111000111001101110000000000110111000111001101110000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000011100110111000011011100011100110111000000110111000111001101110000011
```

Comment: The length of \$f(n)\$ is [A025169](https://oeis.org/A025169).

Comment: Your example output for f(4) is unbalanced. Maybe there is a typo there.

Answer (score 11):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 45 bytes

The top line is a function that returns the nth digit (0-based).

```hs
(!!)=<<f 1
f d n=1:(f(1-d)=<<[d..n-1+d])++[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfYRvzX0NRUdPWxiZNwZArTSFFIc/W0EojTcNQNwUkGp2ip5ena6idEquprR1tEPs/NzEzT8FWoaC0JLikSEFFoTgjv1wvQwGoVCHaQE/P0MAAqMjQEEgDMZhGYqGJ45GB8f8lp@Ukphf/100uKAAA)

The function `f` generates both \$f(n)\$ with `d=1` and \$g(n)\$ with `d=0`. The top line is a point free version of

```hs
h n = f 1 n !! n
```

where `!!` is Haskells indexing operator.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 71 bytes

Returns the \$n\$-th term, 0-indexed.

Very inefficient because it generates way more terms that needed.

```javascript
n=>(F=n=>n?(g=(n,c=F,h=k=>k>n?0:c(k++)+h(k))=>1+h``)(n-1,g):'10')(n)[n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYzNDoIwEITvPMXe2k2LoRcP4OKNlzAmkMqPlmwJoBfjs9flMl9mMjOv7tNtfn0ue87x0aeBElOtGxLlqx5Js/XU2IkC1UGiovQ6GINm0gGRamemtkXNubMjlsoVSgze@J6GuOr43oFAKQssLCrBBdxZKBfwzQCOhiEYZFRlv8xH3uLcn@Y4HmOs0h8)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 32 bytes

```
⊞υ10Ｗ¬›Ｌ⌈υ⊗θ⊞υ⪫10⭆υ⪫10⪫…υ⊕λω§⊟υＮ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7LCsIwEEX3fkVwNYEKuhRXUkEqthT8gjQdmkIeNU5s/fqYFNx4V8Pcw@FKJbx0QsfYhpeCULDtYb/lp82sRo0MGkdw9SgIPdzRDqSgFstogoHAecEuLnQae3jyFPZz3NxoIYsK9iA/2qEW099/PcuP1Fgqt5aVlR4NWko6nd1zdqYpbTIQnKmyPS7QZppnfArUBNOlZRmL8ZgSd2/9BQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs the `n`th digit (0-indexed). Explanation:

```
⊞υ10
```

Start with the base case.

```
Ｗ¬›Ｌ⌈υ⊗θ
```

Repeat until the string is way long enough.

```
⊞υ⪫10⭆υ⪫10⪫…υ⊕λω
```

Generate the next iteration.

```
§⊟υＮ
```

Output the `n`th value.

Comment: @Arnauld You're right, I wasn't generating sufficient terms to get `n=1` correct. Should be OK now.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>59</s> 52 bytes

```ruby
p(1).step &f=->n,a=0{p 1
n.times{|x|f[x+a,1-a]}
p 0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0DDUFOvuCS1QEEtzVbXLk8n0dagukDBkCtPryQzN7W4uqaiJi26QjtRx1A3MbaWq0DBoPb/f0NDQwMDIAbTSCw0cQMA)

- Saved 7 Bytes thanks to @ovs
  Outputs terms indefinitely on new lines.
  Straightforward approach:

> actually saved many bytes by using ovs idea to use just one function behaving differently

````ruby
p 1           we first print a 1 because we call g(1..) note that we do not need to close an infinite stream.  
1.step &$     again: we call g(1..

$f=->n,a=0    a=0->g() , a=1->f()
{p 1          put a 1: open [
(a...n+a).map{|x|$f[x,1-a]}  inner calls
p 0           put a 0: close ]
```
````

Comment: [52 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0DDUFOvuCS1QEEtzVbXLk8n0dagukDBkCtPryQzN7W4uqaiJi26QjtRx1A3MbaWq0DBoPb/f0NDQwMDIAbTSCw0cQMA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 49 bytes

Since it's [been beat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240773/56656) here's my original Haskell solution.  It takes a radically different approach.

```hs
x!y|q<-x++y++[0]=y++0:q!(y++q++[0])
1:[1]![1,1,0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v0KxsqbQRrdCW7tSWzvaINYWSBlYFSpqAOlCsIgmV5qtoVW0YaxitKGOoY5B7P/cxMw8BVuF3MQCXwWNgtKS4JIiveKM/HJNBRWFksTsVAVzAwOFtP@GhoYGBkAMppFYaOJ4ZIg2gSpm0NW9Q9DFIyk@AQ)

Looking at this, you can start to see the relationship between the lengths of the terms and the Fibonacci sequence as pointed out by [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/240769/mutually-recursive-lists/240775#comment543331_240769).

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>19</s> 18 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
TλèληJ01ý11ì00«}I£
```

Outputs the first \$n\$ bits. Could alternatively output the 0-based \$n^{th}\$ bit by replacing the trailing `£` with `è`.
Becomes slower the larger \$n\$ becomes, because it will calculate all bits representing \$f(n)\$ first, before leaving just the first \$n\$.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9vc2FiaWX//1TOu8OozrvOt0owMcO9MTHDrDAwwqt9ScKj//8yMA)

Could have been shorter if 05AB1E had a `to_string` function for lists somehow, since `¯¸λèλη` (7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)) already outputs \$f(n)\$ including commas and spaces.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ARcA6P9vc2FiaWX//8KvwrjOu8OozrvOt///NA).

**Explanation:**

```python
 λ               # Start a recursive environment
  è              # to output the (implicit) input'th value
T                # Starting with a(0) = "10"
                 # Where every following a(n) is calculated as follows:
   λ             #  Push all previous terms as list: [a(0),a(1),...,a(n-1)]
    η            #  Pop and push the prefixes of this list
     J           #  Join each inner prefix-list together to a string
      01ý        #  Join this list of strings with "01"-delimiter
         11ì     #  Prepend a leading "11" to the string
            00«  #  Append a trailing "00" to the string
 }               # After the recursive function:
  I£             # Leave just the first input amount of digits
                 # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```